# Is it okay to omit "he was" in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> The man stuttered too, perhaps when (he was) confused.

Can I omit "he was" in this sentence? Why or why not?

Comment: But there are no "following sentences"!

Comment: You can drop "he was" but only if you say "when"; it gets dicey if you say "whenever" instead of "when".

Comment: @TRomano you mean it makes more sense to use "whenever"?

Comment: Not more sense, only that you shouldn't omit "he was" if using "whenever".  USUAL:  He stuttered when (he was) confused. He stuttered whenever he was confused.  ODD: He stuttered whenever confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can omit "he was". Because "confused" is an adjective, and "the man" is the only NP, "confused" could only apply to "the man".

However, with or without "he was", the sentence doesn't make sense. Either he did or didn't stutter; there is no "perhaps" about it.

- The man stuttered too, when confused.

Or, to make sense of "perhaps":

- The man stuttered too, perhaps **because he was** confused.

This phrasing requires "he was".

But you could rearrange it thus:

- The man, perhaps because he was confused, stuttered.

or thus:

- Perhaps because he was confused, the man stuttered.

Answer (score 2):

The man stuttered, perhaps, when he was confused.

You can reduce the time relative clause "when he was confused" by deleting its subject + to be as the subject of the main clause and when-clause is the same person.

So it's also correct to say:

The man stuttered, perhaps, when confused.